# How do I display a template to only specific product pages in Magento?

Tags: php, xml, magento

I have a parts configurator that I only want to have appear for a certain product SKU. In my catalog/product/view.html file I have included the following code:

```
    <?php 
if ($_product->getSku() == '10007-') {
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('partfinder_selector')->toHtml();
}
?>
```

Then, in the xml file for the configurator:

```
<catalog_product_view>
<reference name="content">
  <block type="partfinder/selector" name="partfinder_selector" before="-" template="partfinder/selector.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

The issue is, with this setup, the configurator appears on all product pages.  Do I have something wrong in my code, or is there a better method for what I am trying to accomplish.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Note, this solution doesn't require any 'configurator xml', so you can leave that out.  You'll be able to use an if statement like in your example to select only the sku you want.

Create directories:

```
app/code/local/Partfinder/Selector/Block
app/code/local/Partfinder/Selector/etc
```

For your app/etc/modules as Partfinder_Selector.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Partfinder_Selector>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Partfinder_Selector>
    </modules>
</config>
```

In your app/code/local/Partfinder/Selector/etc as config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Partfinder_Selector>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Partfinder_Selector>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <partfinderselector>
                <class>Partfinder_Selector_Block</class>
            </partfinderselector>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

In your app/code/local/Partfinder/Selector/Block as Menu.php:

```
<?php
class Partfinder_Selector_Block_Menu extends Mage_Core_Block_Template 
{    

}
?>
```

In your app/design/pkgname/themename/template/Partfinder save a file called selector.phtml containing your block code.

In catalog/product/view.phtml:

```
<?php if ($_product->getSku() == "10007-"): ?>  
  <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('partfinderselector/menu')->setTemplate('partfinder/selector.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, when you use `echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')--setBlockId('partfinder_selector')->toHtml()`
 Magento tries to output the static block with the id partfinder_selector.

Second, `<reference name="content">` refers to the content block which is a "core/text_list" which automatically outputs its children, so your block will be automatically output by the content block.

The solution would be, in your xml file use

`<reference name="product.info"> instead of "content"`

and use `$this->getChildHtml('partfinder_selector')` in catalog/product/view.html

Answer (score 0):

You are require to follow below steps to do this:

1) - In the /Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml you have to write the following thing:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <module>
                <class>>Namespace_Module_Helper</class>
            </module>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_view>Namespace_Module_Helper_View</product_view>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

2) - Register module in magento module list under app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml

```
<config>
        <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends />
        </Namespace_Module>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

3) - You have to create your file under /Namespace/Module/Helper/view.php.

Please find below code

```
class KNamespace_Module _Helper_View extends Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View
{

  public function initProductLayout($product, $controller)
    {
        $design = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/design');
        $settings = $design->getDesignSettings($product);

        if ($settings->getCustomDesign()) {
            $design->applyCustomDesign($settings->getCustomDesign());
        }

        $update = $controller->getLayout()->getUpdate();
        $update->addHandle('default');
        $controller->addActionLayoutHandles(); 
        $update->addHandle('PRODUCT_TYPE_' . $product->getTypeId());
        $update->addHandle('PRODUCT_' . $product->getId());
       //update code 

        if(preg_match('/10007-/',$product->getSku())){$update->addHandle('PRODUCT_NEWLAYOUT');}

        $controller->loadLayoutUpdates();
        // Apply custom layout update once layout is loaded
        $layoutUpdates = $settings->getLayoutUpdates();
        if ($layoutUpdates) {
            if (is_array($layoutUpdates)) {
                foreach($layoutUpdates as $layoutUpdate) {
                    $update->addUpdate($layoutUpdate);
                }
            }
        }

        $controller->generateLayoutXml()->generateLayoutBlocks();

        // Apply custom layout (page) template once the blocks are generated
        if ($settings->getPageLayout()) {
            $controller->getLayout()->helper('page/layout')->applyTemplate($settings->getPageLayout());
        }

        $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
        $root = $controller->getLayout()->getBlock('root');
        if ($root) {
            $controllerClass = $controller->getFullActionName();
            if ($controllerClass != 'catalog-product-view') {
                $root->addBodyClass('catalog-product-view');
            }
            $root->addBodyClass('product-' . $product->getUrlKey());
            if ($currentCategory instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Category) {
                $root->addBodyClass('categorypath-' . $currentCategory->getUrlPath())
                    ->addBodyClass('category-' . $currentCategory->getUrlKey());
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

1. add code in catalog.xml:-

   partfinder/selector.phtml

Hope this will work for you. :)
Best of luck.
[Jitendra Padmashali](https://plus.google.com/117858265525619638144/posts), KrishInc